# SQLite CursorLoader selection parameter - date format the column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

In my android app I have a database that stores dates as long values from System.currentTimeInMilis. I now want to query specific days using a CursorLoader. This is what I have tried:

```
DateFormat sameDayCheckerformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String selection = sameDayCheckerformatter.format(ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY) + "=" + sameDayCheckerformatter.format(dayInMilis);

return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null);
```

This did not work as I expected:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

But I can not find a solution. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you apply format to `ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY`?
It looks like a `String` representing a column name. 
Also you need to surround the formatted date with quotes.
Change to this:

```
String selection = ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY + " = '" + sameDayCheckerformatter.format(dayInMilis) + "'";
```

**Edit**:
If the column `ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY` has integer values then you don't need to format at all:

```
String selection = ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY + " = "  + dayInMilis;
```

**Edit 2**: You need `strftime()` function:

```
String selection = 
    "strftime('%d-%m-%Y', " + ItemEntry.COLUMN_DAY + " / 1000, 'unixepoch') = '" + 
    sameDayCheckerformatter.format(dayInMilis) + "'";
```

Comment: I think I am a bit confused. what I want is to query all results from the database that would be included in the in the day specified. So if we apply date format to this date in the database would it equal the day specified, if so query it.

Comment: that does not work tho because both values are in miliseconds. I want to round them to days before I compare.  1550235576924 is not the same as 1550235576555 but they are both the same day.